# intersection of convex sets

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Is there an example of a family of convex sets with this property?

"Assume we have n convex sets and intersection of any j sets of this sets is non empty which j = 2, 3, ... , n-1 and intersection of all sets (n sets) is empty."

Comment: There is [a theorem by Helly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly's_theorem) which says that, if all the intersections of $(1+\text{dimension of the ambient space})$ convex sets are non-empty (and if there are finitely many sets), then the intersection of all those sets is non-empty.

Answer (score 0):

Take three general lines in the plane.

Any two of them intersect in a single point, but since they are not concurrent the intersection of all of them is empty.